# PostgreSQL: How to incorporate a WHERE clause in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm brand new to `PostgreSQL` and trying to query some data from a test table I created.  The table is named `Activity` and it has a structure that looks as follows:

```
id    Color    Dimension    Style    COUNT    SUM    Date
```

The data looks as follows:

```
Color   Dimension    Style    COUNT    SUM    Date
Blue    Circle       Large    4        800    6/19/2020
Blue    Circle       Small    5        1500   6/19/2020
Blue    Square       Medium   1        15     6/19/2020
```

Submitting the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM public."Trades"
```

... gets me all records (as expected).  So far, so good.

However, now I would like to retrieve only the records in the `Dimension` column that equal `'Blue'`.  To do that, I submit the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM public."Activity"
WHERE Dimension = 'Blue';
```

I get an error that says:

```
ERROR:  column "dimension" does not exist
LINE 2: WHERE Dimension = 'Blue';
              ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "Activity.Dimension"
              ^
```

So, I try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM public."Activity"
WHERE "Activity.Dimension" = 'Blue'
```

Again, I get an error message that says:

```
ERROR:  column "Activity.Dimension" does not exist
LINE 2: WHERE "Activity.Dimension" = 'Blue';
```

Can someone please tell me how to successfully introduce the `WHERE` clause in this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Postgres will lowercase the column unless you surround it with double quotes.  `WHERE "Dimension" = 'Blue';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the table name:

```
select *
from "Activity"
where "Color" = 'Blue';
```

Also some notes:

1. I think you've mixed up `Color` and `Dimension`, I've corrected that.
2. I suggest using snake_case in naming to avoid having to wrap names in `"`
3. If you're querying one table, you don't have to specify it in the `where` clause, that's why I wrote `where "Color" = 'Blue'` instead of `where "Activity"."Color" = 'Blue'`

Answer (score 0):

Just say `Activity.Dimension` without the quotes.

Comment: this will not work. as the table name and column names are not in lower case. you have to put schema name, table name and column name in double quotes(")

Comment: Not true at all. Did you try it? I did.